# Is there a way to "clean" an accept header in Java?

Tags: java, http, servlets, jersey

So if someone sends in this accept header:

```
*/*'"!@$^*\/:;.,?{}[]`~-_<sCrIpT>alert(81363)</sCrIpT>
```

it is returned in the response using Jersey.  I need to intercept this and escape it.  I have not found any way to do this.  Any help?

Comment: Search for "URL Encoding", "HTML Encoding" and "JavaScript Escaping" and apply to all non-alphanumeric characters, as appropriate for your output location.

Comment: I believe you misunderstand.  If someone sends this to me, how do I clean it?  I can't seem to find a way in Java to change an incoming or outgoing Accept header...

Comment: You shouldn't bother trying to clean it.  It's a losing battle to try and remove anything that you know is unsafe, because you'll never know everything that is unsafe.  Instead, you should simply make sure that what you serve is safe - and the encoding mechanisms I mentioned will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use filters to intercept your request and do the cleanup before they reach your service class. Check this [example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-filter-and-how-do-i-use-it.html).

Comment: I was looking in Jersey.  I still can't find it, so here is the secret sauce:  ((HttpServletResponse) res).setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(((HttpServletRequest) req).getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT)));  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can read request headers, and modify response headers in this way (you can not modify request headers, it's a read only map):

```
@Context HttpHeaders headers;

@Path("yourPath")
public Response yourMethod(){
    List<String> accept = headers.getRequestHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT);
    if ( accept contains invalid characters)) {
        do something    
    }
    //If you set a null value, the header is deleted. 
    //Anyway, deletion is useless, if you have not yet set 
    // the Accept header on the response.
    return  Response.ok().header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, null).build();
}
```

Comment: I need something a bit more universal than this.  Also, I am using JAXB, so I don't get all that stuff...